How to export javascript files from typescript files?
I have a javascript library and want to migrate it to nx workspace library but on creating a react library with @nx/react:lib and using vite as bundler and it does not able to resolve the library export correctly
This is my directory structure of my library

index.ts is the main entry file which is configured automatically by nx generator and from this point I am trying to export the utils.js function so that I can use that in apps but typescript is failing to recognize it as module and Vite throws error
Could not find a declaration file for module './lib/utils'. '/Users/kuliza-1002/Desktop/saas-app/libs/fuse/src/lib/utils.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here is the github repo
https://github.com/devmadhavvv/nx-repo
I tried to create a utils.d.ts to declare the utils functions as module but still can't able to export the functions

you can use type srcipt compiler.
you need typescript npm package: npm i -D typescript
then you need to config it in tsconfig.json and add your file like this: {"files" : [file1,file2] }
more info: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html
then you can compile you typescripts, run: tsc
